# Как сгруппировать данные из другой модели django?

Tags: python, django

мудрейшие! Есть модели Протокол, Заявитель, Тип помощи. Заявитель привязан привязан к конкретному протоколу и в свою очередь к конкретному типу помощи. Через slug получаем страницу конкретного протокола, и заявителей относящихся с этому протоколу. Необходимо вывести список заявителей сгруппированных(и отсортированных) по типу помощи. На выходе должно быть вот так:
1. Материальная:
-заявитель;
-заявитель;
2. Похлопать по плечу :
-заявитель;
-заявитель;

Шаблонизатор jinja2

models.py:

```
class Protocol(BaseModel):
"""Протокол"""
title = models.CharField(
    _('Название'), max_length=255, db_index=True, blank=True,
    help_text=_('Обязательное поле')
)
slug = models.SlugField(
    _('Алиас'), max_length=150, db_index=True, unique=True,
    help_text=_('Латинские буквы и цифры')
)
date = models.DateTimeField(_('Дата протокола'), default=utcnow)
class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('Протокол')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Протоколы')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class HelpType(BaseModel):
"""Тип помощи"""
title = models.CharField(
    _('Название'), max_length=255, db_index=True, blank=True,
    help_text=_('Обязательное поле')
)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('Тип помощи')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Типы помощи')
    ordering = ('ordering',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class Applicant(BaseModel):
"""Заявитель"""
    name = models.CharField(
        'ФИО', max_length=255, help_text=_('Обязательное поле')
    )
    position = models.CharField(
        'Должность', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True
    )
    cause = models.CharField(
        'Причина', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True
    )
    in_fond = models.CharField(
        'Время пребывания в фонде', max_length=255, null=True, 
         blank=True
    )
    summ = models.IntegerField('Сумма ходатайства', null=True, 
    blank=True)
    summ_text = models.CharField('Сумма ходатайства прописью', 
    max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    protocol = models.ForeignKey(
       'Protocol', verbose_name=(_('Протокол')), 
        related_name='applicants', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True, null=True
    )
    help_type = models.ForeignKey(
         'HelpType', verbose_name=(_('Тип помощи')), 
         related_name='applicants', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
         blank=True, null=True
    )

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Заявитель'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Заявители'
    ordering = ('ordering',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

views.py

```
class ProtocolView(BaseTemplateView):
"""Страница протокола"""
template_name = 'protocols/protocol.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs = super(ProtocolView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    current_page = get_object_or_404(
        models.Protocol.objects.published(), slug__exact=kwargs.get('slug')
    )
    applicants = models.Applicant.objects.published().filter(protocol=current_page.pk)

    kwargs.update(
        current_page=current_page,
        applicants=applicants,
    )
    return kwargs
```

разрулил на шаблоне вот так:

```
{%- if applicants -%}
{%- for group in applicants|groupby('help_type.title') -%}
  <p>Тип помощи: {{ group.grouper }}</p>
  {%- for applicant in group.list -%}
    <p>{{ applicant.name }}</p>
  {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%}
```

но у меня нет сортировки, пробовал менять сортировку у заявителей и типов помощи - безрезультатно. Сортируются по id типов помощи. Или можно как-то во views.py этот вопрос решить?

Comment: Можно во view, почему бы нет?

Comment: Так разрулили или нет? Если да, то зачем вопрос? Вам группировка или сортировка нужна? Непонятно в чём именно у вас проблема.

Comment: Доброго дня, удалось сделать группировку(это и был вопрос), но не так как хотелось(отсюда появился второй вопрос). То есть если удастся отсортировать сгруппированные данные в шаблоне, то вопрос закрыт,  так как сортировка по типу помощи должна быть